# Write text with JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write Text for Related Results but I want the text to be different for every page, I think it can be done with document.write
but I am not sure of the exact way of doing it. I am using blogger which places the same code for every page, so you can understand I can't use different JS for every page, there should be a way out to Have a different text for Related Results on every different page.
Here is the link to the test page http://bloghutsbeta.blogspot.com/2012/04/testing-slider.html
down there images are Related Results.

Here is my JS

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var defaultnoimage=&quot;http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_u4gySN2ZgqE/SosvnavWq0I/AAAAAAAAArk/yL95WlyTqr0/s400/noimage.png&quot;;
    var maxresults=14;
    var splittercolor=&quot;none&quot;;
    var relatedpoststitle=&quot;Related Results&quot;;
    </script>
```

Comment: Does the url change with a pattern that you can pick with js and change the content based on it?

Comment: Looks like you're using jQuery. Open to jQuery solutions?

Comment: I am not using Jquery for this thing, It is pure JS, no libraries involved.

Comment: @nuno_cruz well I would love to do what you are saying but that would need some good js to be written, so I am just asking for one simple text method one that is provided like down there.

Comment: @CryOfFaclon: Where do you get the related results from? E.g., how do they change from page to page?

Comment: Well they are based on a script, I don't show results manually its automated, here is the script http://bloghuts.googlecode.com/files/related-postsupdated.js

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you can do is 
make your code like this

```
<div id="posttitle" style="display: none;">Related Results</div>
```

and then add this variable to your JS

```
var relatedpoststitle = document.getElementById(&quot;posttitle&quot;).innerHTML;
```

It should help you.

Comment: Your method seems interesting to me as It is like what I want, but It is not working :(

Comment: Your quoted `var relatedpoststitle...` line is a syntax error. You don't use `&quot;` for quotes in JavaScript.

Comment: it is what Cryoffalcon provided me with, maybe this could be the reason my script was not helpful for him, why don't you try this without &quot cryoffalcon?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I corrected the error of @quot; by replacing it with " but still it is saying UNDEFINED?

Comment: You get `undefined` because the element has not loaded at the time JS is executed. Look for `window.onload` or `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is check for the title for each page. I belive each page would have a unique title. Based on that title you can write text for that page using JS
var pageTitle = document.title;

```
if(pageTitle == 'testpage')
{
  document.getElementById('myID').text = 'Your text goes here'
}
else
{
  document.getElementById('myID').text = 'Your new text goes here'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is some hack:

```
window.onload = function() { // Wait for the DOM to be loaded
    var t = document.getElementById('posttitle')
    switch ( window.location.pathname ) {
        case '/2012/04/testing-slider.html':
            t.textContent = 'Some title'
            break
        case '/2012/05/some-thing.html':
            t.textContent = 'Some other title'
            break
    }
}
```